# Alternative to python-config callable from within Python

Tags: python, introspection, cpython, compiler-flags, python-c-extension

I want to have a Python script build a Python C extension module for whichever version of the Python interpreter with which the script is being run.

To this purpose, I want to dynamically acquire the relevant C compiler flags – one way to accomplish this would be to grab the output of the `python-config` CLI tool, e.g. like so:

```
subprocess.check_output(["python-config", "--includes"])
```

Unfortunately, on systems on which several versions of Python are installed, this method may not find the right `python-config` – that is to say, the `python-config` associated with the currently-running version of Python. (Also, it is a bit ugly, methodologically.)

Is there some way that I can acquire this information from within Python – something perhaps like Numpy’s `get_include`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer: it is the built-in `sysconfig` module. [image: the sysconfig module]

… offering methods to access the same information `python-config` provides, including but not limited to:

- `get_python_version()` (which does what you think),
- `get_paths()` (yields a `dict` with many useful paths),
- `get_config_var()` and `get_config_vars()` (these return strings and a huge `dict` respectively, to sift through all of the low-level configuration options),
- `get_config_h_filename()` (yields the source `config.h` file),
- `parse_config_h()` (for only the most intrepid configuration plumbers)

… the first two of which will likely suffice, for anyone seeking `python-config` values without having to go through an embarrassing `subprocess` dance to get it.

- [Official Python 3 `sysconfig` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html)
- [Python 2 `sysconfig` PyMOTW example](https://pymotw.com/2/sysconfig/)